# Using SUM function in cell formula yields #NAME error

Tags: excel, vba

I am experiencing the following issue:

The relevant line in my VBA macro reads like this

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & intv).Formula = "=SUM(Sheet2!" & Cells(row_1,col_1).Address(0,0) & ":" & Cells(row_2, col_2).Address(0,0) & ")"
```

where intv, row_1, row_2 and col_1, col_2 are integers that will only make sense in the context of the whole macro.

Using debug.print() on this formula yields exactly the result I intend, but for some reason when I run the macro, the cell

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & intv)
```

only displays `#NAME` error.

What is even more peculiar, is I can **remove** this error by double clicking the cell and pressing Enter - **without changing** the content of the cell. Using

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Calculate
```

does not resolve the error, however.

**Worth noting:**

I am using

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

before this line. But putting

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

before does not change the outcome. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this, or has anyone experienced something similar ?

**Edit**: Here is the original code.

```
Sheets("Übersicht").Range("N" & tcurrencyc).Formula = "=SUMME(Ergebnisse!" & Cells(resultr - activet, resultc).Address(0, 0) & ":" & Cells(resultr, resultc).Address(0, 0) & ")"
```

and debug.print of the formula part reads:

```
=SUMME(Ergebnisse!P8:P8)
```

as atm the variable `activet` is set to 0.

Comment: As posted that code couldn't possibly run. You are missing a quote and you misspelled `Address`

Comment: What is `Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & intv).Formula` right after setting the formula?

Comment: It **displays** "#NAME error", but what formula is written in the respective cell? Maybe one of the used parameters  (row_1, col_1 etc.) is wrong.

Comment: This is most likely not the real code, probably instead of `SUM` there is some local version, posting fake code makes it difficult to answer.

Comment: @Rory sorry about that, should be fixed.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it reads "=@SUM(Sheet2!P8:P9)", this will change with changing values of row_1, col_1 etc. Tried different values and this part seems to be working fine. (Not sure why there is an '@' but it shouldn't be the problem ?)

Comment: @BrakNicku you're right, added the original.

Comment: @FaneDuru I added the output of debug.print() along with my original code.

Comment: Please, try `FormulaLocal` instead of `Formula`. Or write in the formula the standard 'SUM' instead of German 'SUMME'. If I remember well, the standard way does  not work only in `FormatConditions` and it was a trick involving to previously write the formula in a cell and then extract it as `FormulaLocal`... I mean, in VBA, programmatically.

Comment: @FaneDuru thank you, that did the trick !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `.Formula` only accepts english formulas like: `=SUM(Ergebnisse!P8:P8, Ergebnisse!Q8:Q8)` English separator is `,`
2. `.FormulaLocal` accepts localized formulas. So on a german Excel it would accept: `=SUMME(Ergebnisse!P8:P8; Ergebnisse!Q8:Q8)` German separator is `;`

With VBA code I recommend always to use `.Formula` in combination with the English formula. This will work on any Excel world wide! Don't worry on a German Excel you will see the German Formula in your cell (it get's translated automatically) only the VBA code has the English version.

`.FormulaLocal` changes with every Excel language. That means your code will only work in the same language version your code is written in. So if you run the German code in a French Excel it will not work. Version number 1 will always work in every language.